# How to partition data using multiple properties in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, partitioning

How to partition data using multiple properties in Azure Cosmos DB? I tried to check in the Azure documentation, but couldn't find a solution.

Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: Please edit your question and include what you mean by multiple partition keys.

Comment: Yes, I might have used incorrect word. I want to partition data using multiple columns/properties. E.g. UserId and ProductId. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to partition data using multiple columns/properties. E.g.
>   UserId and ProductId. Is it possible to do so?

Currently it is not possible to partition a collection on multiple properties. You could create a composite key (e.g. `UserProductId`) that stores both user id and product id and use that for partitioning of data.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav for clarification and suggestion.

Comment: Gaurav, can you please help me with deciding best possible partition key. Please refer [this](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Lra3qlUwJ2WYjzfn1) image where I have mentioned possible partitions can be created depending on partition key. Can you please suggest me which column is best candidate for partition key?

Comment: I would recommend asking a separate question for this. Also, please read this excellent guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at doing this now, and just wanted to share this doco that I came across from Microsoft which talks about this practice:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/synthetic-partition-keys

Basically the answer, as the above Accepted Answer confirmed a few years ago, is "use a synthetic partition", and this document goes into more detail about this solution.